# SQL Insert statement not working - RDS

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, rds

I am running a mysql database on an RDS instance.

My table schema is:

Table: users, Columns:

```
_id - int(11) AI PK
username - varchar(50) UNIQUE
email - varchar(100) UNIQUE
```

Im then using the following SQL statement to attempt to enter a new record

```
INSERT INTO usrdb.users (username, email)
VALUES ("admin", "admin@test.com")
```

This statement just times out (30 seconds) repeatedly.

I know from experience that a simple insert statement shouldn't take anywhere near this length of time.

Comment: `INSERT INTO usrdb.users (username, email)
VALUES ('admin', 'admin@test.com')`

Comment: Unbelievable. I could have sworn I was doing this before and switched just to check. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Gotta change the double quotes to single quotes :)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm

Answer (score 0):

This query example should work :

```
 INSERT INTO `table`(`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('varchar','varchar')
```

Check if there is a duplicate Exception raised.